# ElasticSearch histogram aggregation by a single nested object value

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have an index of users created with this mapping:

```
PUT /users
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "id":   { "type": "string"   }
        "signed_up_at":   { "type": "date"   },
        "trades": {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "id":         { "type": "string"  },
            "type":       { "type": "string"  },
            "created_at": { "type": "date"   }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Example document:
{
  "id": "0",
  "signed_up_at": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000000",
  "trades": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "type": "BUY",
      "created_at": "2018-01-02T00:00:00.000000"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "SELL",
      "created_at": "2018-01-03T00:00:00.000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

My objective is to understand the time between the account creation (signed_up_at) and the first trade. I want my data aggregated by monthly cohorts. This is the query I'm building:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "cohorts": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "signed_up_at",
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "trades": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "trades"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "days_before_first_trade": {
              "histogram": {
                "script": " --HERE I NEED TO FIND THE DATE OF
                              THE FIRST TRADE AND CALCULATE THE
                              DAYS BETWEEN THE ACCOUNT CREATION --",
                "interval": 1,
                "min_doc_count": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find a way to access the oldest nested trade. I need the script to return days, seconds or any kind of time value. I tried by accessing directly to the JSON document (params['_source']...), it works but it is really, really slow.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how this approach is going to work, the first aggregation gets you the number of sign ups per month. Is trades an array or do you have individual documents for each trade? Can you show us example documents?

Comment: I've updated the question with better examples. The biggest limitation is that I cannot access, in the script, the parent properties.

Comment: In theory you would want to sort the nested docs by created date and take the top entry